# Meditation practice among the chess elite?

Tags: preparation, performance

My question is simple.  Do we know of any 2700+ caliber players that regularly cite meditation as part of their lifestyle / preparation?

It's not hard to find meditating chess players, but I'm wondering about its use in top practice and perhaps if there are any studies that have attempted to measure its effects.

Comment: Viktor Korchnoi was a yoga practitioner.

Comment: The reason I ask is from personal experience:  basic mindfulness meditation (for about 20 mins/day) seemed to help my game.  I use a week word "seemed" for a reason, but by all appearances it helped my concentration and focus.

Comment: There had been a chess24 brodcast of some top-level chess tournament where they would ask that to every participant in the post-game-analysis.  If you spent some time digging into the video archives you might find it. I think I remember Topalov was among those that meditated but I  am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these sources for "meditation" among the past 2 worlds champions:

Carlsen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELoJbv4bCHw

Anand:
https://badrirag.wordpress.com/category/viswanathan-anand/

Q : Do you practise meditation and if so, how effective do you find it?

A:  I don’t meditate regularly and hence I do not know the extent to which it can help.

Based on my Google research, some chess players meditate, but I see no evidence proving that top chess players meditate more than the general population

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any studies. A quick search turned up [this article](http://en.chessbase.com/post/nakamura-has-open-forum-q-a-with-fans) where Nakamura says

> I don't do anything special to prepare myself although I do occasionally meditate!

Answer (score 1):

Found this article on GM Jonathan Rowson:

http://www.tm.org/blog/people/british-chess-champion/

Comment: That is interesting.  Thanks!